# Set-Cookie present in the header but not being set in the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, cross-domain, setcookie

We are currently up against an error with our client/api cookie generation. We are using Angular 12 and NGINX for a frontend server running with SSL on a subdomain of cms.domain.co.uk; the backend is running node.js with pm2 on a subdomain of api.domain.co.uk:3067 with SSL.

Our Backend nodejs file has the following CORS options snippet:

```
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'https://cms.domain.cloud',
    credentials: true,
    methods: 'GET, POST, OPTIONS',
    allowedHeaders: 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Set-Cookie, Authorisation, Accept'
}));
```

We are setting the cookie in the node.js file as follows:

```
response.cookie('LoginCookie', sid, {httpOnly: true, secure: true, SameSite: "none"});
```

We have tried every feasible combination of origins, tags, and policies and we are now officially stumped. Excuse our naivety in CORS as we have come from non-cross origin background.

The responsive header from the server contains the set-cookie tag but the cookie isn't being set in the browser, allow credential controls is set to true in both the POST and OPTIONS as well as having the origin set to avoid CORS errors.

This is the pre-flight OPTIONS header sent:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQUrv.png)

This is the POST header sent with the Set-Cookie tag:

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YismJ.png)

By starting another window of chrome with the using chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security, the browser acknowledge the existence of the cookie in one section but not in the other:

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ACWu.png)

Any feedback or help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: httpOnly: true - Javascript does not have access to the cookie. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to retrieve de value of the 'LoginCookie' key Set-Cookie header, and store it to browser by `document.cookie.setItem( 'LoginCookie', <data>)`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Axios on the frontend for calling an API, add `withCredentials: true` and then it will work.

Example:

```
const fetcher = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:5000/api/",
    timeout: 2000,
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true, "Content-Type": "application/json" },
});
```